# How to update attribute everytime a new object is added in CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7

I have a core data model that looks like this: 
[image: Core data model]

Notice both the `total` attribute and `array` relationships in both the `MonthlyYearSale` and `PCSParticularProduct` entities; with their relationships between the other entities following a `one-to-many` relationship.

**Just a further note:**

The `PCSParticularProduct` entity's `total` attribute stores the total sale figure made in a particular product id across the month.

The `MonthlyYearSale` entity's `total` attribute stores the total monthly sale based on a collection of total sales calculated from a set of 24 or so products across that month.

**Question:**

When I add a child object in the parent entity's array, how can I update the `total` attribute on that same parent? I have two entities in which I wish to update the `total` figure based on the objects added into the `array` relationship attribute. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a wrapper method in your managedObject subclass like

```
- (void) insertChild:(NSManagedObject *)object {

call core data method to add the object (or set the object's parent)
update total
}
```

Or you could use KVC to observe changes to the child array and respond by updating the total.  I would recommend the wrapper approach since it does not require that the parent be instantiated.

Comment: Could you explain more about your KVC approach pls. There is a method that coredata already adds when a relationship is defined which allows you to add/remove children to the array, but adding children ofcourse doesnt update specific attributes such as my `total` attributes that can be found in the first two entities in my coredata model diagram.

Comment: You could observe changes to the array (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  When an object is inserted into the array, your managedObjectSubclass's observeValueForKeyPath function can update the total.  Perhaps a better (and yet another) approach would be to update the total when when the parent object is saved, assuming it has changes.  When an object is saved, your managedObjectSubclass's -willSave function is called, and you can do your calculations there.

Comment: Another take on the last approach would be to have each new child object update the parent's total when the child object is saved and has changes that would affect the parent's total.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing pickwick. The date now loads fantastically fast, ofcourse thats because everything has been cached. Only the initial download takes forever as it fetches thousands of sale date from the past year. But once the file has been updated locally, I only fetch the data since the last time that the data was updated with a date handler. Its pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using CoreData fields to manage those values as they're calculated values. There's nothing to win by saving them unless you have thousands of objects and counting over and over becomes a performance problem. But by then you wouldn't be using CoreData anymore but rather SQLite directly.

You could implement the total like follows:

.h:

```
@property (readonly) int total
```

.m

```
- (int)total;
{
     int subTotal = 0;
     for (ProductSale sale in self.arrayOfChildren)
     {
          subTotal = subTotal + sale.value;
     }

     return subTotal;
}
```

It will work as a property but it will give you the actual value every time. I'm pretty sure it needs all objects to be read into memory, if this is not the case you should look further into Core Data aggregation:

[How to count in coredata (aggregation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342540/how-to-count-in-coredata-aggregation)

I woul suggest that if you need a lot of SQL-like functions on your data like aggregates you should investigate if direct usage of SQLite would be a better options. CoreData over SQL is more for storing your models in a related way, not an actual database:

http://www.objc.io/issue-4/SQLite-instead-of-core-data.html

Perhaps you could do a mix of both approaches but I don't know how it would work out if you would access the same DB via CD and directly at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for posting. Yep I have over 15,600 objects and growing, so counting over and over will become a performance problem, hence my question. P.S. I am using core-data so that I can benefit from the relationships, and access relational data only when needed. There must be an efficent way of handling the total Value of the arrayOfChildren. As a side note will bindings somehow help in this situation?

Comment: I assume all objects are not ready in memory so my method would not suffice anymore.

Take a look here then:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342540/how-to-count-in-coredata-aggregation

Also a very good read:
http://www.objc.io/issue-4/SQLite-instead-of-core-data.html

I updated my original answer

Comment: Take a look where? you said take a look `here` and `then`, I have received the then link but not the here link.

Comment: @Pavan I am not sure how to edit these comments into a more readable state but there are two clickable links in my original reply and my comment below it.  

** First link--> **  
  
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342540/how-to-count-in-coredata-aggregation  
  
**  Second link-->   **

http://www.objc.io/issue-4/SQLite-instead-of-core-data.html